Run e2e tests in Laravel app with different .env file
I want to use some environment variables for e2e testing like integrated Laravel unit test. My test needs to use separate database for safety refreshing data and another app setting. Do you now some case were i can use some command to run my app with different .env file? Thanks.
In perfect i want run command for set .env.e2e for my Laravel app and return basic .env after tests finished.
